# Bigquery data transfer trigger on-demand

Tags: google-bigquery

I have implemented a transfer job from S3 to BQ and configured it to be on-demand. I have used [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/s3-transfer) guide. How can I trigger a data transfer configured to be on-demand via either the console or a CLI / API calls?

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this using cli or API?

Answer (score 0):

To run your job using the [Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery/transfers), click on your job, then click the option 'More' on the upper right corner and click the option 'Refresh Transfer'

Also, it seems like there is currently some improper behavior with the new BigQuery UI, as well as the transfer jobs. Most likely, you will see in the Console that your transfer job, even if configured as 'On-Demand', shows in transfer details as scheduled to run every 24h, but running this command (1), you will see how the job schedule option 'disableAutoScheduling' is set to true. Bear in mind this product is still in Beta, so there is still work in progress.

(1): bq show --format=prettyjson --transfer_config [resource_name]